# Scala partition a set

Tags: scala, set, partition

I was looking at how to split a set in two based on the contents of a third set. Accidentally I stumbled upon this solution:

```
val s = Set(1,2,3)
val s2 = Set(4,5,6)
val s3 = s ++ s2

s3.partition(s)
res0: (scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int],scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int]) = (Set(1, 2, 3),Set(5, 6, 4))
```

The signature of `partition` is as follows:

```
def partition(p: A => Boolean): (Repr, Repr)
```

Can someone explain to me how providing a set instead of a function works?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A set `s: Set[A]` *is* a function `A => Boolean`: for any value `a` of `A` you return whether `s` contains `a` or not.

```
scala> val f: Int => Boolean = Set(1,2,3)
f: Int => Boolean = Set(1, 2, 3)

scala> f(1)
res0: Boolean = true

scala> f(4)
res1: Boolean = false
```

---

If you look a the [documentation for .apply](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.SetLike@apply(elem:A):Boolean), you'll see

> def **apply**(elem: A): Boolean
>   Tests if some element is contained in this set.
>
> This method is equivalent to contains. It allows sets to be
>   interpreted as predicates.